# How can I put more time or even see the time set on "snap set system snapshots.automatic.retention="?

Tags: snap, snapshot

I am fighting vs snapshots. In https://snapcraft.io/docs/snapshots says that by default the time of the autosaves is 31 days, I want to set it to forever, but it just let me put values of hours, not even days...
I want to know the value already set on "snapshots.automatic.retention=" and how I can set it to forever

Comment: How do we set the retention period to 60 days?  I've tried 

`$ sudo snap set system snapshots.automatic.retention=60d
 error: cannot perform the following tasks:
 - Run configure hook of "core" snap (run hook "configure": snapshots.automatic.retention  cannot be parsed: time: unknown unit d in duration 60d)
`
and looked for specific time parsing. I've failed. Are only hours, h, supported?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible, having looked at the source code for snapd, specifically the section dealing with [snapshots](https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/blob/master/overlord/configstate/configcore/snapshots.go).

However, if you want to retain the snapshots for a long period, I'd recommend just backing them up separately. Snapshots taken by snap whether automatic or manual, are just plain zip files in `/var/lib/snapd/snapshots`.

For example, I just did `snap install null` (an empty snap I published) and `snap remove null`. Here's the snapshot:

```bash
root@localhost:/var/lib/snapd/snapshots# ls -l
total 4
-rw------- 1 root root 812 Feb 13 23:30 2_null_null_3.zip
```

Back that up and you're done.

Comment: Thanks. How can I set "snapshots.automatic.retention=" again to it's default value?

Comment: Run `snap help set` to find out you need an exclamation point. So `sudo snap set system snapshots.automatic.retention!`

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo snap set system snapshots.automatic.retention=no
```

will disable deletion, according to the documentation.